# TFS build definition permissions and groups inheritence with user having membership to multiple groups

Tags: tfs

I have following users groups

- Builders

  - User1
  - User2
- Contributors

  - User1 (Note this is member of Builders also)
  - User2 (Note this is member of Builders also)
  - User3
  - User4
  - User5

and following build definitions (Dev build definitions outnumber prod build definitions by many times)

- Dev Builds

  - Build Definition 01
  - Build Definition 02
  - Build Definition 03
  - Build Definition 04
  - Build Definition 05
- Prod Builds

  - Build Definition 51
  - Build Definition 52

Since Dev build definitions outnumber the prod build definitions by many times, the default at "All Build Definition" level is to allow access to both Contributors and Builders. I want to deny Contributors access to Prod build definitions. However, if I explicitly Deny, User1 and User2 who are members of both groups gets "denied" that access. The only other option I can use is "Inherited Allow" and "Allow". How else can it be achieved? I would like to keep the default this way so that less number of build definitions require override unless there is no other way.

Here is a typical permission

- All Build Definition

  - View Build Definition (Picked one of the permission for sample)
  - Builders - Allow
  - Contributor - Allow
- One of the Prod Build Definition

  - View Build Definiton (Picked one of the permission for sample)
  - Builders - Inherited Allow (Options are Allow, Deny, Not Set)
  - Contributor - Inherited Allow (Options are Allow, Deny, Not Set)

Here is what happens

- Inherited Allow at Contributor - All users have access
- Deny at Contributor - User 1 and User 2 lose their access regardless of any permissions at Builders group

Comment: Have you already tried to set "Not set" to see if that works?

Comment: Yes, "Not Set" is equivalent to "Inherited Allow" in which case all users get access.

Comment: Yes @PatrickLu-MSFT it have me the right direction. It is not yet implemented as some other higher priority items came in front of it. It is planned in next 2 weeks. I will surely post the update once it is done.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. According to TFS permission setting, most groups and almost all permissions, **Deny** trumps **Allow**. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to Deny, that user will not be able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to Allow.

Details you could take a look at the tutorial in MSDN: **[About permissions and groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/about-permissions?view=vsts)**

To achieve what you want, you can **create a new group** such as *DenyProGroup*.  Adding the others developers except user1/user2 in Contributors to this group. Such as User3/User4/User5 in your case.

For this group, set *View Build Definiton* permissions to “Deny” of all Prod Build Definitions. For **Contributors** and **Builders**, set the same permissions to”Allow”. Saved Changes. Then the user3/4/5 will lose the ability to view Prod Builds but user1/2 still have.